# Replace http from url to https in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column in dataframe, which contains a few urls
For Example before:

```
| url                | anydata            |
| -------------------| ------------------ |
| https://google.com | anydata            |
| http:/bing.com     | anydata            |
| https:/yahoo.com   | anydata            |
```

how i can replace all http to https?
For example after:

```
| url                | anydata            |
| -------------------| ------------------ |
| https://google.com | anydata            | 
| https:/bing.com    | anydata            |
| https:/yahoo.com   | anydata            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace(r'^http\b', 'https', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  url  anydata
0  https://google.com  anydata
1     https:/bing.com  anydata
2    https:/yahoo.com  anydata
```